# MySQL not all results are shown

Tags: php, mysql

i have made i small membersearch for my site that looks for first name oder second name in my database. all members are inserted by the same way but i get not always a result back. if no member with a typed name is found than i get a message. that seams to work, but some times i get no message or if there are more than one results i get not all of them.
here is my code i use.

```
<form id="tfnewsearch" method="POST" action="admin_search_member.php">
    <input id="tfq" class="tftextinput4" name="q" size="21" maxlength="240" value="Mitglied suchen..." />
    <input type="submit" name="startsuche" value=" " id="tfbutton4">
</form>
```

and that's my query

```
if(isset($_POST['startsuche'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Mitglieder WHERE vorname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['q']))."%' OR nachname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['q']))."%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."    </pre>\n".mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
?>
<div id="body_box_tabs">
    <div class="tabcontents">
        <div id="view1"> 
            <p style="color: #003137; font-weight: bold;">Das gesuchte Mitglied   existiert nicht!</p>
            <a href="./admin_mitglieder.php"><input class="button-link" type="submit"  value="Zurück"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php        
} else {
    echo $_POST['q'];
?>
<div id="body_box_tabs">
    <div class="tabcontents">
        <div id="view1"> 
<?php        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "show me the found member";
    }
} 
?>
```

I hope some one can help me with this.

Comment: It looks like you *never* output the first row you got. So you'll always have one less result shown than what was returned by the query. - Try and remove the first `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`.

Comment: why are you using triple wildcard `%` - `...LIKE '%%%".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['q']))."%%%'...`?

Comment: Be careful, mysql_* functions are deprecated and can cause security issues. You'd better use mysqli_* or PDO extensions

Answer (score 1):

You're basically fetching and then discarding the first row of the query result. This will cause the "does not exist" message to be shown when there are no rows, will cause no output when there's one row returned, and will cause (n-1) outputs when n>1 rows are found. You will never see the first row of the result this way.

Either remove the first `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`, or change your loop:

```
do {
    echo "show me the found member";
} while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: thanks. i only hat to remove the first fetch. your method works but than i always got two commas. but you pointed me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this code block:

```
<?php        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "show me the found member";
    } 
} 
?>
```

Do this:

```
<?php        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo $row['field_name'];
    }
} 
?>
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: Not until the OP stops fetching and discarding the first row returned.

Comment: True didn't notice that.

Comment: with 
        <?php echo "show me the found member"; ?>
i ment the $result :)
it's working now. thanks also to you for your help :)